# Visual Studio PackageVersion vs semver

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I am trying to display the semantic version number of my ASP.NET application, which I have set to 1.1.0 in my project properties. However, when I retrieve the version number at runtime, it appears as 1.1.0.0. I want to know how to correctly set the version number to follow semantic versioning, as well as how to add a build number for each build.

Here is the code I am using to retrieve the version number:

```
@{
    var version = GetType().Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString();
}
```

This is what I see on the frontend:

[image]

I want to update my code to display the version number as 1.1.0 and follow semantic versioning. Additionally, I want to be able to add a build number for each build.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use [`ToString` overload accepting `int fieldCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version.tostring?view=net-7.0#system-version-tostring(system-int32)) parameter:

| fieldCount | Return Value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | An empty string (""). |
| 1 | major |
| 2 | major.minor |
| 3 | major.minor.build |
| 4 | major.minor.build.revision |

```cs
var version = GetType().Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString(3);
```

Note that in case of using additional labels (like pre-release or build metadata) you might need to use `AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute`:

```cs
var infVersion = assembly.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>();
string version = infVersion.InformationalVersion;
```